# Does the ESP32's ADC have a part number/datasheet of its own?

Tags: adc, datasheet, esp32, reference-materials

I need to get as much information as I can about this ADC and I wasn't able to find ample amount of it from the datasheet and reference manual of the ESP32-WROOM-DevKit. Did anyone manage to find the reference number of the ADC itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean, "reference number".

If you are assuming the ADC is a separate chip, The ADC is part of the ESP32 microcontroller. There isn't a separate ADC chip.

If you are looking for how to refer to specific ADC pins when writing code, it really depends on which IDE you are using.  Please update your question with specifics about your IDE.

Comment: I was referring to the datasheet of the said ADC, or its characteristic reference that lets you know which ADC you have , however, if it is a part of the MCU then the question has already been answered.

Comment: Some SoC's do incorporate on-die peripherals which are also available independently in standalone form. In this case the peripheral may indeed have its own product/model number and documentation. I don't think this is the case with the ESP32 ADC, though.

Comment: @A.H.Z The ESP32's ADCs characteristics are documented by [Espressif](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/adc.html).  They're not terribly accurate, especially at the ends.  If you need better accuracy you can use strategies like biasing your analog signal into the middle of the ADC range.